# what is the output of fgetc under the special case where int width == CHAR_BIT

Tags: c, integer, standards, fgetc

In section 7.19.7.1 of C99, we have:

> If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by stream is not set and a
>   next character is present, the fgetc function obtains that character as an unsigned
>   char converted to an int and advances the associated file position indicator for the
>   stream (if defined).

As I understood it, `int` type can have the same width as an `unsigned char`. In such a case, can we conclude that fgetc would only function correctly if `int` width > CHAR_BIT.

(with reference to the comment by blagovest), does C99 specify when the standard library is to be expected, or whether a conforming implementation can implement part but not all of the standard library?

Comment: "int type can have the same width as an unsigned char" - I really, really doubt that and I would be really shocked, if there's a platform, where this is true. Where did you read this? Or you understand this from that quote? Because it doesn't say such thing.

Comment: Please don't place two questions in one. Open another one for your question about `int32_t`.

Comment: @KirilKirov see the 24 bit machine described in http://stackoverflow.com/q/8007825/1016492

Comment: The issue is not about object "widths", but with ranges. If `int` ranges are -32767 to 32767 and `unsigned char` ranges are from 0 to 255 (or 32767) there will be no problem with `fgetc`. **I mean range of characters in the file system, at the Operating System level**

Comment: @pmg, barring one special case, knowing the width tells one the range, and vice versa

Comment: @tyty: in the case of `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int) == sizeof(void *) == 1`, I highly doubt there will be files, an underlying operating system, much less a standard library, so this shouldn't be a concern for non-embedded code.

Comment: @tyty: right, I edited my comment to better reflect what I meant. Anyway, the width and range of objects are not necessarily (nearly) equivalent: there can be padding bits in the width.

Comment: @pmg C99 defines the precision of a signed integer to be the number of value bits and the width (of signed integer types) to be the precision + 1. So width does not count padding bits. See 6.2.6.2/6

Comment: Ok; I didn't mean "width" as defined by the Standard (6.2.6.2): I meant it as size in bits as reported by `CHAR_BIT * sizeof (int)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgetc` returns `EOF` on an end-of-file or error condition.

Otherwise, it returns the character that was read, as an `unsigned char`, converted to `int`.

Suppose `CHAR_BIT == 16` and `sizeof (int) == 1`, and suppose the next character read has the value 0xFFFF.  Then `fgetc()` will return 0xFFFF converted to `int`.

Here it gets a little tricky.  Since 0xFFFF can't be represented in type `int`, the result of the conversion is implementation-defined.  But typically, the result will be -1, which is a typical value (in fact, the only value I've ever heard of) for `EOF`.

So on such a system, `fgetc()` can return `EOF` even if it successfully reads a character.

There is no contradiction here.  The standard stays that `fgetc()` returns `EOF` at end-of-file or on an error.  It doesn't say the reverse; returning `EOF` doesn't *necessarily* imply that there was an error or end-of-file condition.

You can still determine whether `fgetc()` read an actual character or not by calling `feof()` and `ferror()`.

So such a system would break the typical input loop:

```
while ((c = fgetc()) != EOF) {
    ...
}
```

but it wouldn't (necessarily) fail to conform to the standard.

> *(with reference to the comment by blagovest), does C99 specify when the standard library is to be expected, or whether a conforming
>   implementation can implement part but not all of the standard
>   library?*

A "hosted implementation" must support the entire standard library, including `<stdio.h>`.

A "freestanding implementation" needn't support `<stdio.h>`; only standard headers that don't declare any functions (`<limits.h>`, `<stddef.h>`, etc.).  But a freestanding implementation may provide `<stdio.h>` if it chooses.

Typically freestanding implementations are for embedded systems, often with no operating system.

In practice, every current hosted implementation I'm aware of has `CHAR_BIT==8`.  The implication is that in practice you can *probably* count on an `EOF` result from `fgetc()` actually indicating either end-of-file or an error -- but the standard doesn't guarantee it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes on such a platform there would be one `unsigned char` value that would not be distinguishable from `EOF`.

`unsigned char` is not allowed to have padding bytes, so the set of values for `unsigned char` would be a superset of the possible values for `int`.

The only hope on such a platform that one could have is that at least `char` would be signed, so `EOF` wouldn't clash with the positive `char` values.

This would probably not be the only problem that such a platform would have.